# Rails to_json include multiple belongs_to and has_many references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following Model structure:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites
end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :server
  has_many :plugins
end

class Plugin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :website
end
```

When I call `server/1.json` I only get the JSON of the `Server` attributes. What I want is to include all its `websites` and the `websites` to include all their `plugins`. How would I achieve this?

```
format.json { render :json => @server.to_json(:include => :websites) }
```

This works for including the `websites` but I want to include the references inside the websites too.

Comment: since you want to fetch plugins connected to a server, you should add to the server class `has_many :plugins, :through => :websites` and do `@server.to_json(:include => [:websites, :plugins])`

Comment: @Zippie But that shows me all plugins for a server. I want the plugins that belong to it's website. And that website belongs to a server.

Comment: oh, sorry, missunderstood

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is

```
format.json { render json: @server.to_json(include: {websites: {include: :plugins}}) }
```

You can pass in a hash to include as opposed to an array and in doing so specify nested includes.

Comment: It's so elegant, I love Ruby=)